# Is there and method to open shortcutfile.exe by hotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there and method to open shortcutfile.exe by hotkey ? withen the keyboard but i need other method not by cliking proprties and assign shortcut. i tryed to use program called winhotkey but it doesn't open the shortcut.exe file it opens the main program file is there any way to assign any keyboard key to open that kind of shortcut file ? and thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to pin the application on your Windows Task Bar, then launch it via the Windows TaskBar shortcuts (Win + number).
Number can be 1 to 9, or 0 for the 10th application.

So let’s say you pinned your application in 3rd position in your taskbar, you can launch it by pressing "Windows" + "3".

Short note: If the app is open, the shortcut will put the focus on it, if the app is closed it will open it.
If you want to open a new session with your app (and it is already opened), you can press "Win" + "Shift" + number.

Comment: so there's no an option to open a shortcut via diractly number 5 for example without need to open it beside win key ?

Comment: As far as I know for Windows, not without a 3rd party program such as an autohotkey program.